# Count the total number of auto-populatedbutton on the website using windows form web browser c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

How can I count the total number of auto-populated button on the website using windows form web browser c#?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5QUo.png

The id name of the button is :

```
Button 1 : button1OO_PMC_Grd_Lst_ct102_Btn_Lst
Button 2 : button1OO_PMC_Grd_Lst_ct103_Btn_Lst
Button 3 : button1OO_PMC_Grd_Lst_ct104_Btn_Lst
```

The button is auto-created depends on the file created. The button is created using asp.net page. I don't have access to the source code of the asp.net page, that's why I created a windows form web browser to get the total count of the auto populated button.

Comment: Uh... is this asp.net or WinForms? From what I can see, if you got the name pattern, you can just run a regex on the html of the page and see how many distinct matches you find.

Comment: The page is created using asp.net. But I'm counting the count using windows form web browser.

Comment: Then this is not an asp.net question.